# Nginx - all requests received goes to same website

Tags: nginx, webserver, vhosts, ispconfig

I tried to search for a solution to this problem for some time now.
But nothing seems to work.

The issue is that every request goes always to the same website (first website configured on ISPconfig. If I disable the first one, it goes to the second - which is now the first). It doesn't even go to default.

Investigating this issue, I found that probably nginx is receiving the wrong host in the request (I have a cname for my subdomains in my domain provider dns server).

So I ran tcpdump, but I found out that every request is actually received correctly:

```
root@server:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# tcpdump -n -S -s 0 -A 'tcp dst port 80' | grep "Host"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
Host: cartoes24.wagnerux.de
Host: cartoes24.wagnerux.de
Host: cartoes24.wagnerux.de
Host: test.wagnerux.de
Host: test.wagnerux.de
Host: test.wagnerux.de
```

My vhost confs:

-- cartoes24 vhost:

```
server {
        listen 192.168.1.1:80;


        server_name cartoes24.wagnerux.de;

        root   /var/www/cartoes24.wagnerux.de/web/;



        index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;



        error_page 400 /error/400.html;
        error_page 401 /error/401.html;
        error_page 403 /error/403.html;
        error_page 404 /error/404.html;
        error_page 405 /error/405.html;
        error_page 500 /error/500.html;
        error_page 502 /error/502.html;
        error_page 503 /error/503.html;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        location = /error/400.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/401.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/403.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/404.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/405.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/500.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/502.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/503.html {

            internal;
        }

        error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/cartoes24.wagnerux.de/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/cartoes24.wagnerux.de/access.log combined;

        location ~ /\. {
                        deny all;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                        access_log off;
                        log_not_found off;
                        root /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/acme/;
                        autoindex off;
                        index index.html;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location /stats/ {

            index index.html index.php;
            auth_basic "Members Only";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client2/web1/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
        }

        location ^~ /awstats-icon {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files /14d86c825b76b9bcc54ed6b1dbff2e23.htm @php;
        }

        location @php {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

        location /cgi-bin/ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            root /var/www/clients/client2/web1;
            gzip off;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
            fastcgi_index index.cgi;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }
}
```

-- test vhost:

```
server {
        listen 192.168.1.1:80;


        server_name cartoes24.wagnerux.de;

        root   /var/www/cartoes24.wagnerux.de/web/;



        index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;



        error_page 400 /error/400.html;
        error_page 401 /error/401.html;
        error_page 403 /error/403.html;
        error_page 404 /error/404.html;
        error_page 405 /error/405.html;
        error_page 500 /error/500.html;
        error_page 502 /error/502.html;
        error_page 503 /error/503.html;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        location = /error/400.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/401.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/403.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/404.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/405.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/500.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/502.html {

            internal;
        }
        location = /error/503.html {

            internal;
        }

        error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/cartoes24.wagnerux.de/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/cartoes24.wagnerux.de/access.log combined;

        location ~ /\. {
                        deny all;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                        access_log off;
                        log_not_found off;
                        root /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/acme/;
                        autoindex off;
                        index index.html;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location /stats/ {

            index index.html index.php;
            auth_basic "Members Only";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client2/web1/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
        }

        location ^~ /awstats-icon {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files /14d86c825b76b9bcc54ed6b1dbff2e23.htm @php;
        }

        location @php {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

        location /cgi-bin/ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            root /var/www/clients/client2/web1;
            gzip off;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
            fastcgi_index index.cgi;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }
}
```

-- default vhost:
server {
listen 80 default_server;

```
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
    error_log /home/wagner/default_server_error.log;
    return 444;
}
```

I'm sorry if this question is already answered, but every "solution" that I found didn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please run `nginx -T` and add the output to a pastebin and post the link in your question

Comment: Hello Tarun,
I found out the problem. It was an issue with ispconfig (something i'm using in my server). I had some bad IP config in the virtual host configs.
To fix it, I have to input the actual server IP and not the * symbol, and then it works.
Should I close/delete this question?

Comment: I think you can put your own answer and explain the issue. Might help someone in future making similar mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution.
I'm using ISPconfig, and in the IPv4/IPv6 config of the Web Domain tab in the WEBSITE options, I had to insert the actual local IP of my server, and not the *.
I don't know the reason for it, but it works like this.